# Java for loop to determine legal triangles

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, optimization

Three numbers form a legal triangle if the sum of two of the sides are greater than the third. So [7,3,6] and [8,8,8] are valid, whereas [2,6,4] and [8,6,1] are not. I am given an array with only 3 values.

```
public boolean isLegalTriangle(double[] lens){
  a = lens[0]
  b = lens[1]
  c = lens[2]

  return ( a+b > c && b+c > a && a+c > b )
}
```

This is the code I have written. Is it possible to rewrite this with a for-loop? (hard-coding the indexes seems primitive)

Comment: Sure it's possible.. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Why do you think your current solution is primitive? This seems like a perfectly valid solution to me, given that ```n``` is both small and fixed.

Comment: If I am given an array such as [4,-1,8,2,5,3] and asked to count how many legal triangles can be made using these numbers, then I will need to use multiple loops for it. So I am trying to evolve my code to the next level.

Comment: @BCronyn - that seems like a totally different requirement and question to what you've asked above

Comment: try with recursive it will give easy solutions

Comment: @BrianAgnew – I definitely see what you mean. One question returns true or false and the other returns an integer (counting the number of legal triangles). I would think of my above comment-question as an extension to my initial question, but not entirely different. The basic logic still stands: 3 numbers are compared according to the above conditions, but this time, the boolean value is an if statement which increments a count instead of returning true/false.

Comment: You left the part "if I am given an array such as [4,-1,8,2,5,3] and asked to count how many legal triangles can be made using these numbers" out, and this changed the meaning of the question completely. Do the values need to be consecutive? I guess not, and then the answer by "helpYou" doesn't apply. And you also forgot "The hint is that we will need 3 nested for-loops".

Answer (score 2):

You can use **modulo** to achieve this:

```
public boolean isLegalTriangle(double[] lens){
    int l = lens.length;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < l; i++) {
        if ( lens[i%l] + lens[(i+1)%l] <= lens[(i+2)%l] ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You will have 3 iterations:

- i = 0

  ```
  lens[0] + lens[1] <= lens[2]
  ```
- i = 1

  ```
  lens[1] + lens[2] <= lens[0]
  ```
- i = 2

  ```
  lens[2] + lens[0] <= lens[1]
  ```

Comment: Your answer is clever and it answers my immediate question – I am not denying that. However, if I was given an array of let's say 6 values and asked to count how many legal triangles can be made using these numbers, your above code would just test the 3 touching values [i,i+1,i+2]. Is there a way to test all the values?

Comment: Then you need something like this:
`int count=0; for ( int i = 0 ; ... ) { for ( int j = i+1 ; ... ) { for ( int k = j+1 ; ... ) { if ( isLegalTriangle(lens[i],lens[j],lens[k]) {count++;} }}} System.out.println(count);` where:
`public boolean isLegalTriangle(double a, double b, double c){
  return ( a+b > c && b+c > a && a+c > b )
}`
but it can be asked as a different question. We hope that our solutions will help many people. And it's better to have different questions for different problems.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* sort the incoming array (using [Array.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(double[])) - this will sort the array *in-place*), and then compare the largest (first) entry vs. the sum of the 2nd/3rd entries, avoiding the multiple clauses in your 'if' statement.

However the above seems concise and readable, and I would favour that generally.

Answer (score 1):

Sum the values up. If any value is greater than or equal to half the sum then it's not a valid triangle.

```
public boolean isLegalTriangle(double[] lens){
  double max = (lens[0] + len[1] + lens[2]) * 0.5;

  return (lens[0] < max) && (lens[1] < max) && (lens[2] < max);
}
```

using for loops:

```
public boolean isLegalTriangle(double[] lens){
  double max = 0.0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      max += lens[i];
  max *= 0.5;

  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      if(lens[i] >= max)
          return false;
  return true;
]
```